# Generate all combinations of a multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object

### Problem

I would like to generate all combinations for a template-like object which could take several children in which some define the desired output as an array. Those children can have as well children (there is virtually no limit).

### Example Input

```
const input = {
  a: [true, false],
  b: ['first', 'second'],
  c: {
    d: [true, false]
  }
};
```

### Example Output

```
const output = [
  {
    a: true,
    b: 'first',
    c: {
      d: true
    }
  },
  {
    a: true,
    b: 'first',
    c: {
      d: false
    }
  },
  {
    a: true,
    b: 'second',
    c: {
      d: true
    }
  },
  {
    a: true,
    b: 'second',
    c: {
      d: false
    }
  },
  //...
]
```

### Question

What could be the JavaScript function to transform the input into an output?

### What has been tried?

I tried taking the original function from this question and make it more ES compliant but this is not working when having multiple children inside the object.

```
function combinations(input, keyIndex = 0, current = {}, result = []) {
  const keys = Object.keys(input)
  const key = keys[keyIndex]
  const values = input[key]

  for (const index in values) {
    current[key] = values[index]

    if (keyIndex + 1 < keys.length) {
      combinations(input, keyIndex + 1, current, result)
    } else {
      result.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(current)))
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a recursive function which separates all key/value pairs and build a new cartesian product by iterating the values, if an array with objects call `getCartesian` again and build new objects.

This works for nested objects as well.

```js
function getCartesian(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var temp = [];
        r.forEach(s =>
            (Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]).forEach(w =>
                (w && typeof w === 'object' ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                    temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [k]: x }))
                )
            )
        );
        return temp;
    }, [{}]);
}

var input = { a: [true, false], b: ['first', 'second'], c: { d: [true, false] } },
    cartesian = getCartesian(input);

console.log(cartesian);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much that's exactly what I was searching for! I like what you did with the entries/reduce methods.

Comment: Thanks for simple code, is there any way to do a generator ( yield ) version of this function?